# Is there anyway to link seperate silverlight4.0 projects which were in different directories for integration using prism4.0

Tags: silverlight-4.0, prism

I have two seperate silverlight4.0 projects which were not in same solution.I need to integrate these projects using Prism4.0.

Is there anyway to link these projects with out intoducing both into same solution.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I did it by refering the solution of my module project into my main project without copying it to the main project's folder

Now both the projects are in different directories.

Then I excluded the App.xaml file from the module project and introduced module-export page.

And then in the hosting application's property I made a change to include the module's zap file.

And it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

There is another [better] way to do that without having both projects to the same solution. You can use the features that allows you to configure the `ModuleCatalog` from a xaml file, in which you put the information about the referenced modules, in order to avoid doing that as "Project References". You'll just have to ensure that you copy the necessary project outputs (XAP files) to the ClientBin directory of your Web project.

Here's a snippet of a module catalog (catalog.xaml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Modularity:ModuleCatalog
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:Modularity="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity;assembly=Microsoft.Practices.Prism">
<Modularity:ModuleInfo 
    Ref="Solution1.ProjectA.xap"
    ModuleName="Solution1.ProjectA"
    ModuleType="Solution1.ProjectA.Module, Solution1.ProjectA, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
<Modularity:ModuleInfo 
    Ref="Solution2.ProjectB.xap"
    ModuleName="Solution2.ProjectB"
    ModuleType="Solution2.ProjectB.Module, Solution2.ProjectB, Version=1.0.0.0"/>
</Modularity:ModuleCatalog>
```

and here's a nippet from the BootStrapper:

```
public class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
    {
        Modularity.ModuleCatalog.CreateFromXaml(new Uri("catalog.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This method is working fine..

I changed the start up class name of my module files
then build each module xap with Module Export attributes in the startup page, and then added that XAP file into main project

And loaded each project by calling the module name

Here is the snippet

```
Imports Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity
Imports Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions.Modularity
Imports System.ComponentModel.Composition
Imports Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions

<ModuleExport(GetType(App))> _
Partial Public Class App
    Inherits Application
    Implements IModule

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub
    Public Sub Initialize() Implements Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.IModule.Initialize
        TheRegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MyRegion1", GetType(MainPage))

    End Sub
    <Import()> _
    Public Property TheRegionManager() As IRegionManager
        Private Get
            Return m_TheRegionManager
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As IRegionManager)
            m_TheRegionManager = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_TheRegionManager As IRegionManager
    Private Sub Application_Startup(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup

            Me.RootVisual = New MainPage()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Then in Main application

```
Public Class TheBootstrapper
    Inherits MefBootstrapper
 Protected Overrides Function CreateModuleCatalog() As IModuleCatalog
        Dim moduleCatalog As New ModuleCatalog()
                moduleCatalog.AddModule(New ModuleInfo() With { _
                                 .InitializationMode = InitializationMode.OnDemand, _
         .Ref = "App.xap", _
        .ModuleName = "App"})    
       Return moduleCatalog
    End Function    
End Class
```

Then used the module's XAP by calling the loaded module.